# error in Creating new project under webapps tomcat

Tags: java, servlets

How can I create a new project inside tomcat webapps folder for running Servlet's?

I followed the exact pattern as mention in lots of tutorials. Even I copy whole project from webapps(default 'examples' project ) and put at same place (webapps) with different name.

But when I trying to call it from browser (http:\localhost:8080\FIRST\MyServlet), I am getting same error as **HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available.**

What am I doing wrong here, or do I have to mention name of new project in some place in tomcat ??

Can someone help me for this issue please?

I have put my Servlet file inside **webapps->first->WEB-INF->classes**
**MyServlet.class**

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyServlet extends GenericServlet
{
    public void service(ServletRequest req , ServletResponse res)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        res.getWriter().write("<html><body>Hello</body> </html>");
    }
}
```

and this is my `web.xml` file at **webapps->first->WEB-INF->web.xml**

**web.xml**

```xml
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: put your code here, that might be helpful for us.

Comment: Map your context correctly in web.xml file.

Comment: @Killer I don't think that his code is related to his question

Comment: so you think that we don't need to check his web.xml, right... ???

Comment: @Killer I wouldn't say that `web.xml` is code, but it could be a usefull information, thats right

Comment: i also put my code.
please help me why i am getting 404 error

Answer (score 1):

You need to say tomcat where the Servlet is. Therefore, edit your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file and add:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>your-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>your-servlet</servlet-name> <!-- the same as above ! -->
    <url-pattern>/your_servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please note that the Servlet's class should be in the `WEB-INF/classes/` folder, with the complete package structure.

If you don't want to do this hardcoded, you can use Eclipse JavaEE to generate this file for you. Don't forgett to restart the server in both cases!

Comment: And did you restart the Server?

Comment: yes..
this is my web.xml
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
      
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: http:\localhost:8080\FIRST\MyFirstServlet........the url you are hitting is try to hit **MyFirstServlet** which is not present in your configuration. Try hitting MyServlet

Comment: ya sorry ..Its my mistake..
 i am hitting like this http:\localhost:8080\FIRST\MyServlet

Comment: @JayVyas So did _Amit_'s solution work or do you still get an 404?

Comment: try changing FIRST to first. It is usually case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The directory is right , try calling this:

```
http:\localhost:8080\FIRST\MyFirstServlet\
```

instead of

```
http:\localhost:8080\FIRST\MyFirstServlet
```

Comment: `MyFirstServlet` is it under webapps ?

Comment: no its under 
and sorry its MyServlet not MyFirstServlet
webapps->first->WEB-INF->classes->MyServlet

Comment: what do you get when you call this ` http:\localhost:8080\FIRST\ `?

Comment: i am getting this error.
404 , The requested resource is not available.